# changing my @include every 20 or so seconds to include something else

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm designing a web-page that has a certain part in the body changing every 20 seconds to a different "slide", so to say. How I currently set it up;

```
<div id="slide-area">
    @include('slides.slideone')
</div>
```

and after 20 seconds, I want it to be

```
<div id="slide-area">
    @include('slide.slidetwo')
</div>
```

I typed it out really bluntly to just show what I want to achieve.
I've been looking around, trying to find a way to make this happen, but I can't seem to find the right phrasing to find an explanation or tutorial of some sorts. I'm also pretty new to php so my creativity with the language still has to develop. Apologies if it's been asked before.

Comment: For such things you should use JavaScript. Laravel/PHP doesn't change anything in here

Comment: Blade templates are rendered server side, so you cant do this client side. You need to load all of the slides on page load and then use javascript to cycle between them, or make an ajax call to load the next slide from the server every 20 seconds.